# How to create a jagged array by reflection?

Tags: multidimensional-array, f#, type-providers

If I have `elementType` of type `int[]`, for example, `elementType.MakeArrayType()` will throw an exception, and `elementType.GetElementType().MakeArrayType(2)` will create a `int[,]`. How do I create a `int[][]`?

EDIT: this only happens for ProvidedTypeDefinition. It turned out it was a bug in ProvidedTypes.fs

Comment: `typeof(int[]).MakeArrayType()` doesn't throw an exception for me. Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 3):

A jagged array is just an array of arrays, so you do it in two steps:

```
Type intArray = typeof(int).MakeArrayType();
Type jaggedArray = intArray.MakeArrayType();
```

Or in one line:

```
Type jaggedArray = typeof(int).MakeArrayType().MakeArrayType();
```